# Tags: reactive-framework/rx-framework/rx-extensions/reactive-extensions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently there are 12 questions tagged with rx-framework, and 2 with reactive-framework.

The current official name is [Reactive Extensions for .Net (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx), so I was thinking of retagging, does anyone have a preference between reactive-extensions and rx-extensions (I'd go for the shorter version personally)

Comment: How about we ask the potential sponsor of the tag what they prefer?

Comment: Yup, they already have the logo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rx extensions" is a tautology though - the "x" is for "extensions".

I think "rx-framework" is probably the best bet - particularly given the numbers you cited.

Comment: Except that (I can't remember who said it) "there is only one framework, the .Net framework"

Comment: Oops, sorry, I got my numbers back-to-front, it was rx-framework at 12. I'll correct my question accordingly. Is just Rx too short?

Comment: Edited accordingly :) I think "rx" is indeed a bit short, but at least then people will be prompted for "rx-framework" appropriately.

Comment: OK, rx-framework it is. One of the two reactive-frameworks turned out to be mine anyway...